# как заполнить коллонку dataframe по условию наличия значения в дугой колонке?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Я пытаюсь скопировать первую колонку данных по условию наличия значений в другой колонке, но проблема в том что заполнение происходит не по условию

код:

```
data = ({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
         'B': [2, 4, 7, np.nan],
         'C': [3, 5, np.nan, 4],
         'D': [9, np.nan, 8, 6],
         'E': [np.nan, 3, 2, 7]})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for i in df['A'].values:
    df1 = df.loc[df['A'] == i]
    if df1['B'] is not np.nan:
        df1['a_b'] = df1['A']
    else:
        df1['a_b'] = np.nan


   A    B    C    D   E  a_b
0  1  2.0  3.0  9.0 NaN    1
   A    B    C   D    E  a_b
1  2  4.0  5.0 NaN  3.0    2
   A    B   C    D    E  a_b
2  3  7.0 NaN  8.0  2.0    3
   A   B    C    D    E  a_b
3  4 NaN  4.0  6.0  7.0    4
```

нужная колонка копируется полностью, без необходимого исключения данных.

Как можно сделать заполнение с условием?
И если не трудно, подскажите, пожалуйста, еще как можно объединить расслоенные датафреймы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть задачи:

```py
mask = ~df['B'].isna()
df.loc[mask, 'a_b'] = df.loc[mask, 'A']
```

Нужно выбирать строки по булевой маске, причём одной и той же справа и слева от знака присваивания. Ну и копировать данные. А `NA` при этом можно и не копировать - всё, что не будет заполнено в новом столбце, и так будет иметь значение `NA`.

Ну и ещё могу пояснить, почему это `if df1['B'] is not np.nan:` не работает. Слева у вас `pandas.series` (хотя и из одного элемента), а справа скаляр. Естественно, они не могут быть одним и тем же объектом, что вы проверяете через `is`. Но даже если вы возьмёте один элемент, всё-равно будут проблемы с типом и `is` не сработает. Проверять такие вещи можно по-другому, через функцию `isna`: `if not df1['B'].isna().all():`. Но в любом случае лучше не работать с датафреймами через циклы, а делать всё *векторно* - сразу со всеми подходящими элементами столбца, без циклов.

Comment: Большое спасибо, за ответ и за пояснение!

Answer (score 1):

вы хотите получить что-то вроде этого?

```
df['a_b'] = df['A'].mask(df['B'].isna())

>>> df
'''
   A    B    C    D    E  a_b
0  1  2.0  3.0  9.0  NaN  1.0
1  2  4.0  5.0  NaN  3.0  2.0
2  3  7.0  NaN  8.0  2.0  3.0
3  4  NaN  4.0  6.0  7.0  NaN
```

Comment: Спасибо за альтернативное решение!